# PHP new DOTNET() error

Tags: php, iis, wamp

This is a fairly obscure question, but I'm having a devil of a time figuring it out:

I'm running PHP on IIS and am using [PHP's DOTNET function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dotnet.php) to load Microsoft's System.Speech class.

```
<?php

$recognizer= new DOTNET('System.Speech, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35', 'System.Speech');

?>
```

I'm getting a 500 error when I load the above file into my browser.

The error message says:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception
>   'com_exception' with message 'Failed
>   to create COM object
>   `SAPI.SpSharedRecognizer': Access is
>   denied. '

Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like, the web server account (IIS application pool identity) does not have access permissions to the resource file you are trying to open in your code.

Also, there is a problem in your code - the DOTNET function requires two arguments - an assembly name and a class name. You are providing "System.Speech" as the second parameter - this is only a namespace, not the class.